# Display result with 2 decimal points, without 0 at the end

Tags: python

currently i get display:
cup's to litre 0.30
but it needs to be 0.3

there is different unit conversion at the exercise, which need to be displayed with 2 decimal points

This is the code i have

```py
tilavuus = float(input("Anna muunnettava tilavuus desimaalilukuna: "))

Cup_to_litra = tilavuus*0.24

print(f"Cup't muutettuina litroiksi: {Cup_to_litra:.2f}")
print()
```

Display:
Cup't muutettuina litroiksi: 0.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `f"Cup't muutettuina litroiksi: {Cup_to_litra:.2g}"`